# Python sendall() vs C write()

Tags: python, apache, networking

I was looking at some Python code the other day and came across this:

```
   s.sendall(req % (len(body), body))
```

in which len(body) resolved to over 500K bytes. This was being sent to an Apache server, which should cap at 8190 bytes (I found it did when I tried to issue a similar request using C's write() function). So what is so special about sendall() in Python?

Comment: I can assure you that apache is capable of accepting more the 8190 bytes of data in an HTTP request.

Comment: Yes but it should return an error that the request size was exceeded. I configured Apache to use only the default size of 8190 bytes.

Comment: What is `req` in this code? Unless you're sending a query string, the 8190 value is meaningless. What does the request you're sending with C look like?

Comment: Python's socket.sendall is a high level method that does whatever is needed until it either succeeds or raises an error. That includes breaking the message into chunks according to information it gets from the counterpart. 8192 (2**13) bytes is a common max chunk size. C write is a lower level function and it probably tries to send all in one chunk. I am not sure about socket.send, but is *can* return after sending part of a message.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I'll take a look at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you're sending data to Apache or anything else.  The software on the remote end of the socket we're talking about has essentially no direct impact on the difference in behavior between `write(2)` and `socket.sendall`.

The difference is that `write(2)` writes as many bytes as it can, then returns an integer indicating how many it wrote.  It can't write more than you pass it, of course.  But it might write fewer.  There may not be room in the kernel send buffer for all of the bytes passed to it.

Contrast this with `socket.sendall` which writes all the bytes you pass to it.  It does this by calling `write(2)` multiple times, if necessary.

Comment: Well the reomote service does matter considering there is a limit of how many bytes can be received without an error occuring.

Comment: Not really.  The first buffer you hit is in your local TCP/IP stack.  You can easily fill that up before any bytes have even fully traversed the network.  It is a serious mistake to believe that what sequence of "recv" calls happens on the other end of the socket will match up with the sequence of "send" calls you make locally.